# What does ^& represent in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I've noticed the usage of `^&` in:

`(robocopy c:\dirA c:\dirB *.*) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0`

I am wondering what does it do?

Comment: Also see [Is typing %^ into cmd.exe a Windows easter egg?](https://superuser.com/questions/917268/is-typing-into-cmd-exe-a-windows-easter-egg)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `^` symbol is the escape character<sup>*</sup> in Cmd.exe:

> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be treated as ordinary text.
> When piping or redirecting any of these characters you should prefix with the escape character: & \ < > ^ |

[Source](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

However, it has no effect and is actually unnecessary in your command. It appears you want the IF command to be run after the RoboCopy command completes. Therefore you want the `&` to be parsed as the "command separator" command, which [tells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055430/2227908) Cmd.exe to treat your IF statement as a second command that should be executed after running RoboCopy. As a result, this command is equivalent to the one you're using:

```
(robocopy c:\dirA c:\dirB *.*) & IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0
```

---

<sup>*</sup>If `^` is the last character in a command, then it is interpreted as the [command continuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69068/2227908).

#### More Information:

- [Command Redirection & Pipes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)
- [Cmd Syntax on Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)

Comment: @Biswapriyo That's also true, to use `^` for that purpose it must be the *last* character in the command.